# Discord js guildMember getting from user id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i don't know how to get the guildMember from user id in discord.js

i cuoldn't find a solution so i'm asking you

code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '!';

const client = new Client
(
    {
        allowedMentions:
        {
            parse: [`users`, `roles`],
            replieduser: true,
        },
        intents:
        [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        ],
        'partials': [Partials.Channel]
    }
);

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is online!");
});

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if(message.content === "ping")
    {
        message.reply({content: "pong"});
    }
    if (message.content.includes(prefix + 'changeNick')) 
    {
        //message.reply({content: "triggered"});
        var str = message.content;
        const result = str.trim().split(/\s+/);
        if(!result[1])
        {
            console.log("Error in the command");
            message.reply({content: "please include arguments"});
        }
        else
        {
            var member = result[1];
        }
        if(!result[2])
        {
            console.log("Error in the command");
            message.reply({content: "please include arguments"});
        }
        else
        {
            var nickPrefix = result[2];
        }
        if(!result[1] && !result[2])
        {
            console.log("Fatal error in the command");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(message.member);
            //message.member.setNickname("Nick");
            let user = client.users.fetch(result[1].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ''));
            //let user = message.mentions.users.first();
            user.then(function(memberResult) 
            {
                console.log(memberResult.username + "#" + memberResult.discriminator);
                console.log(memberResult);
                console.log(message.member);
            });
        }
    }
});

client.login("MTAzMzI3NDM2NzY1NzkxMDMzMw.GNlpcD.-QrUbUL48L7e-fFHdcExs1R_JjcdCD0F1nAvqg");
```

i've got user but i can't edit the server nickname from this object i need guildMember for this
i'm trying to be able to change nicks of the users with command : !changeNick @User Nick

Comment: Please change your token as it has been leaked

Answer (score 0):

The user ID is the same as the member ID so use `<Guild>.members.cache.get('ID')`, now I don't know on what version of discord.js you are, this will work on v13 and v14, I don't really know about older versions.

P.S. to get the guild inside the messageCreate event you can use `<Message>.guild`, outside an event `<Client>.guilds.cache.get('guild_id')`